# Gregorian date to Persian(or Iranian or Solar) date in power query

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, tableau-desktop

I have a table (for example student_exams_table) and I have a column that contains Gregorian date such as:

| greDate |
| --- |
| 28-8-2021 |
| 29-8-2021 |

How can I convert these values to Persian/Iranian/Solar date in another column(for example persianDate column) in **Power BI** or Tableau?

28-8-2021 should be 06-06-1400

and

29-8-2021 should be 07-06-1400

*Language tag for Perian is fa-IR .

Answer (score 2):

```
=Date.ToText([Column1],"dd-MM-yyyy","fa-IR")
```

eg:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WstA3AiIDI0OlWB0wzxLKiwUA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type date}}),
    
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Persian Date", 
        each Date.ToText([Column1],"dd-MM-yyyy","fa-IR"),Text.Type)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but what is the second code? just an example or I should add it somewhere in Power BI?

Comment: Ron gave you some Power Query code in M language - the second blob of code is an entire sample query you can use by going into get data, choosing blank query, clicking "advanced editor" and paste the supplied code.